# Poster: rounded=false de-centers child box

Tags: beamer, posters

I am using the [Jacobs landscape conference poster](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster), and I want to change the `alertblock`'s edges from soft to sharp. Accordingly, I edited the `beamerthemeconfposter.sty` and set rounded to false. The commented lines are original code.

```
% Alert block definition (with frame)
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount
  %\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0ex,rounded=true,center,dp={2ex}]{block alerted title}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0ex,rounded=false,center,dp={2ex}]{block alerted title}
    \vskip0.01cm
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\large\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.8cm
  %\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5cm, rounded=true,center]{block alerted title}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5cm, rounded=false,center]{block alerted title}
  \setlength{\inboxwd}{\linewidth}
  \addtolength{\inboxwd}{-1cm}
  %\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,wd={\inboxwd},center]{block alerted body}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=false,wd={\inboxwd},center]{block alerted body}
  \setlength{\iinboxwd}{\inboxwd}
  \setlength{\inboxrule}{\inboxwd}
  \addtolength{\iinboxwd}{-0.5cm}
  \addtolength{\inboxrule}{0.5cm}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\iinboxwd}
  \justifying
}
```

The result looks weird, though: The content is now right-aligned, instead of centered as before.

[result http://jb-electronics.de/tmp/poster_1.png](http://jb-electronics.de/tmp/poster_1.png)

Changing the -1cm in

```
\addtolength{\inboxwd}{-1cm}
```

seems to affect the horizontal alignment of the content, but I feel I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the weird part?

Comment: The gray child box is now right-aligned, whereas it is supposed to be centered.